# How to pass multiple value to Builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, builder

I have this

[image]

I want to pass this data

```
var pack = package.data;
```

And use it here

```
// Image.asset("assets/images/vip_1.png"),
    Image.asset("....passed data....."),
```

I tried

```
Image.asset(pack.img),
```

but am getting **null** response.

Please help

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of code.  You can post plenty of text into the original question.

Comment: providing a default image solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

lib/assets/ -> add your images here

then
utils.dart file :

var image1 = 'lib/assets/file_name.jpg';

now on your mainFile :

import your utils.dart file then

Image.asset(image1),

Comment: the image is dynamic. I am fetching the url from database

Comment: then you should try , image.network("url");

Answer (score 0):

-You need to make sure that your future function `readTicket()` returns a value and not null.

-Also wait until returning its value.

-hope I could help